# Convert string date column into standard date in R

Tags: r

Given a dataframe as follows:

```
         date    value   price
0  2010Y1-01m      NaN     NaN
1  2010Y1-02m   365.07  158.18
2  2010Y1-03m   653.19  268.53
3  2010Y1-04m   980.72  331.81
4  2010Y1-05m  1455.60  434.19
```

How could I convert `date` column into standard date, either `%Y-%m-%d` or `%Y-%m`? Thanks.

Out1:

```
         date    value   price
0  2010-01-01      NaN     NaN
1  2010-02-01   365.07  158.18
2  2010-03-01   653.19  268.53
3  2010-04-01   980.72  331.81
4  2010-05-01  1455.60  434.19
```

Out2:

```
     date     value   price
0  2010-01      NaN     NaN
1  2010-02   365.07  158.18
2  2010-03   653.19  268.53
3  2010-04   980.72  331.81
4  2010-05  1455.60  434.19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert to date using `as.Date` and then use `format` to get data in year-month format.

```
df$Date <- as.Date(paste0(df$date, '-01'), "%YY1-%mm-%d")
df$year_mon <- format(df$Date, "%Y-%m")

df
#        date   value  price year_mon
#0 2010-01-01     NaN    NaN  2010-01
#1 2010-02-01  365.07 158.18  2010-02
#2 2010-03-01  653.19 268.53  2010-03
#3 2010-04-01  980.72 331.81  2010-04
#4 2010-05-01 1455.60 434.19  2010-05
```

To convert to date usually we need three components year, month and date. We have year and month in the data we can add a arbitrary date (`01`) using `paste0` here.

---

If `"Y1"` part in year is not fixed and it could be any number (like `"Y2"`, `"Y3"`) you can remove that using `sub` before converting to date.

```
df$Date <- as.Date(sub('Y\\d+', '-01', df$date), "%Y-%d-%mm")
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("2010Y1-01m", "2010Y1-02m", "2010Y1-03m", 
"2010Y1-04m", "2010Y1-05m"), value = c(NaN, 365.07, 653.19, 980.72, 
1455.6), price = c(NaN, 158.18, 268.53, 331.81, 434.19)), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c("0","1", "2", "3", "4"))
```

Comment: Could you please explain `paste0(df$date, '-01'), "%YY1-%mm-%d" ` this?

Comment: Very cool, thanks, I'll test with my real data.

Comment: `%Y-%d-%mm` in `df$Date <- as.Date(sub('Y\\d+', '-01', df$date), "%Y-%d-%mm")` are type errors? Shouldn't it be `%Y-%d-%m`?

Comment: No, we don't remove the "m" in month here since it is fixed always(?). We remove "Y1" only if it changes, so use the second part with `sub` only if you have different values of "Y" in your data.  I am not sure what is the case in your real data.

Comment: `Y1` is fixed in the real data, since all the row's date is cumulative, `1` means `January` here.

Comment: Then you can ignore the `sub` part. First two lines with `as.Date` and `format` is enough.